# Create dockerfile - ASP.NET Core with .NET framework as runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, dockerfile, windows-container

How can I create windows container with **ASP.NET Core** WebApi running on **.NET Framework**?

What base image should I use and how should I build/publish the project? Simple example of dockerfile would be great.

**There is also .NET Framework 4.6.2 project referenced in the WebApi.**

Comment: You can not run full ASP.NET framework inside nanoserver so your base image would need to be based off full .NET framework. (https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet-framework/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with IIS in container. I had to figure out "How to host ASP.NET Core apps in IIS." Tutorial is [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x). This can be done by installing [ASP.NET Core module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1). So in the end my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM microsoft/iis

#install ASPO.NET Core Module (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1)
WORKDIR /temp
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/E/B/6EBD972D-2E2F-41EB-9668-F73F5FDDC09C/dotnet-hosting-2.1.3-win.exe dotnethosting.exe
RUN dotnethosting.exe /quiet /install

#you should restart IIS, but its not necessary, when youre building image
#RUN powershell -command net stop was /y
#RUN powershell -command net start w3svc

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

#replace with your published web application
COPY bin/release/net462/publish .
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have dependency on Full .NET framework your base image would need to be https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet-framework/ and you have to install .NET core into image by yourself. There is no solution provided by Microsoft which has both version of .NET framework in single image.

Comment: I had many problems with this approach. It is not working for me.

Comment: Which `approach` specifically is not working and what is the issue. You are asking for help but yet not providing any relevant information

Comment: This solution was the first I tried. I was not able to build .NET Framework project with microsoft/dotnet base image.

Comment: You need to base off dot-netframework then. It has all optimizations build in for Full .NET framework

Comment: I was thinking about microsoft/aspnet with some additional features. Or microsoft/iis. Do you know what exactly has to be installed explicitly?

Comment: Only microsoft/dotnet-framework has .NET optimization built in. NGEN specifically. See this https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/33. This changes are not present in microsoft/iis etc